# Get the currently created instance as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

In embedded programming, handling interrupts, I need the compiler to know at compile time the address of a class pointer that is a global variable, and a few adresses of IO registers. In order to do this, I'm trying to make a template function handle the ISR and have a pointer-to-class template argument to it:

```
    template<MyClass &C, unsigned char PORT1, unsigned char PORT2>
    void MyISR()
    {
          ...
    }
```

At the initialization function, I want to set the interrupt:

```
template<unsigned char PORT1, unsigned char PORT2>
class MyClass: public MyClassFunctionality
{

    ...

    void init()
    {
        SetISR(MyISR<this,PORT1,PORT2>);
    }
}
```

I know the pointer `this` is not constant, but I also know there will only ever be **one global instance** of the class for each template parameters set.

One solution could be to pass a function pointer to `MyClass::init` and have the template parameters defined at the function call:

```
  MyClass myclassinstance<100,101>;

       ...

  myclassinstance.init(MyISR<myclassinstance,100,101>);
```

I dont like this as it relies in the user of the class setting the pointer and port numbers correctly.
What architecture workarounds can you see that do not involve typing the template pàrameters again for `MyISR<...>` in the call to `init`.

Comment: _"What architecture workarounds can you see that do not involve typing the template pàrameters again for MyISR<...> in the call to init."_ Use `typedef` or `using`?

Comment: That is correct, although I still need to have the user define the `typedef` for me, don't I?

Comment: @gsamaras I need the function MyISR to knoe those values at compile time, If I only pass the class instance those would be known at execution time (i.e. they are not a constant experssion).

Comment: You have issues with your example: `template<MyClass &C,`: `MyClass` is `template`. `SetISR(MyISR<this,PORT1,PORT2>);` could take a `std::function` instead of pointer function to allow to capture the info that you can pass at runtime.

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately ISR functions cannot have any arguments (they are invoked by the hardware on interrupts). You cannot use an object because the `this` pointer is an argument that would need to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

How about specialization ?

```
template <typename T, T* p> struct IsrHelper;

template <unsigned char PORT1,
          unsigned char PORT2,
          MyClass<PORT1, PORT2>* p>
struct IsrHelper<MyClass<PORT1, PORT2>, p>
{
    void operator()() const
    {
        // ...
    }
};


template<typename T, T* p>
void MyISR()
{
    IsrHelper<T, p>{}();
}
```

And then

```
MyClass<100, 101> myclassinstance;

int main()
{
    SetISR(&MyISR<decltype(myclassinstance), &myclassinstance)>);
}
```

In C++17, you may get rid of first parameter with `auto` and have directly:

```
template <auto* p> struct IsrHelper;

template <unsigned char PORT1, unsigned char PORT2, MyClass<PORT1, PORT2>* p>
struct IsrHelper<p> { /**/ };

template<auto* p> void MyISR() { IsrHelper<p>{}(); }

// ...

SetISR(MyISR<&myclassinstance>);
```